# Is there a general Windows event which getting raised when a file was saved (except FileSystemWatcher class)

Tags: c#, windows, events, save

I want to create a programm which checks if the user saved a file via the windows save dialog, is there a general windows event which I can subscribe to?

Comment: What's wrong with FileSystemWatcher ?

Comment: Can you use the FileSystemWatcher to watch the whole disc/discs?

I think the FileSystemWatcher is only good when you got specific directories to watch - but I'm not really sure. :)

Comment: In fact, I use FileSystemWatcher on C:/ (with IncludeSubdirectories = True) when installing third-party setups in order to check what it is doing, and it works very well :)

Comment: Note that you can use different instances of a FileSystemWatcherclass. For example, one to watch the content of a Directory and one to watch the Directory itself (in case the Directory gets moved/deleted/moved to the Recycle Bin etc.)

Comment: Okay. :-) I'll try to create test programm which watches the whole file system. I just have the fear that it will consume lots of resources :-P

Comment: You can configure filters. + `!important` don't process anything in the event handlers. The handlers must be free to notify any event that occurs, otherwise you **will**, soon, begin to lose events. Enqueue the events in one of the many possible ways and process them asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on recommendation of the comments I used the FileSystemWatcher class and used to watch all my discs.

And it's working without any problems referring to performance or resource issues.

Here's a litte test programm I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace FileSystemWatcherTest {
    class Program {
        static List<FileSystemWatcher> fsWatchers = new List<FileSystemWatcher>();

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            foreach(DriveInfo dInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives()) {
                InitializeWatcher(dInfo.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Initialized watcher for disc '" + dInfo.Name + "'");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress 'q' to exit");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;

            DisposeWatchers();
        }

        static void DisposeWatchers() {
            foreach(FileSystemWatcher fsWatcher in fsWatchers) {
                fsWatcher.Dispose();
            }
        }

        static void InitializeWatcher(string DiscPath) {
            try {
                FileSystemWatcher fsWatcherToAdd = new FileSystemWatcher(DiscPath);

                fsWatcherToAdd.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                     | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                     | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                     | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

                fsWatcherToAdd.Created += FsWatcher_Created;

                fsWatcherToAdd.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                fsWatcherToAdd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                fsWatchers.Add(fsWatcherToAdd);
            } catch {
            }           
        }

        private static void FsWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": " + e.Name + " created...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're watching the file activity of each and every disc in the System, without filters. You need to increase the FSW buffer (a lot) and build an extremely smart async procedure to handle the events. Otherwise, this won't work (or work *randomly*). + If you just receive events for file creation, you can remove some of the `NotifyFilters`.